# Why do we need the merge wildcard "_;" in Solidity?

Tags: solidity

I understand it is placed in the the code of modifiers to indicate from where control should pass to the function being modified. Why are we not allowed to just return from the modifier, to do the same?
Also, are there other circumstances where the merge wildcard `_;` can be used?

Comment: I would imagine a return would be popping from the modifier's stack, and modifiers are supposed to just stack on top of method code, and that's where the merge wildcard comes. But that's just a very wild guess.

Comment: What alternative do you propose? With `_` you can include the function multiple times, or evaluate it multiple times.